# Java NullPointerException when traversing a non-null recordset

Tags: java, jdbc, nullpointerexception, resultset

I am running a query on Sybase ASE that produces a `ResultSet` that I then traverse and write the contents out to a file. Sometimes, this will throw a `NullPointerException`, stating that the `ResultSet` is `null`. However, it will do this after printing out one or two records. Other times, with the same exact input, I will receive no errors.

I have been unable to consistently produce this error. The error message is pointing to a line:

```
output.print(rs.getString(1));
```

It appears to happen when the query takes a little longer to run, for some reason. The recordset returns thus far have been very small (4 to 7 records). Sometimes I'll have to run the app 3 or 4 times, then the errors will just stop, as though the query was getting "warmed up". I've run the query manually and there doesn't appear to be any performance problems.

Thanks again!

Comment: I'm wondering if this could be a threading issue. Is your app multi-threaded? Are you running it on a multi-core computer?

Answer (score 3):

Are you sure it's the ResultSet that's null, and not the rs.getString(1)?

This is a typical Java query

```
preparedStatement.setLong(1, primaryKey);
ResultSet rs = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
while (rs.next())
{
  String foo = rs.getString(1);
  if (foo != null)
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I hope you will be doing it well, I mean after calling *rs.next()*.

According to the specs. the ResultSet object should never be *null*, in any case. Even if no records found. Posting the code snippet and the stack trace would definitely help us in giving you a better answer.

**EDIT:**
Since, the error is pointing to that line. It might be calling *toString()* method on *null* String, that caused NullPointerException. Not sure though, it doesn't happen in standard output (System.out.println()) if the passed argument is of String type. But you are using *output.print()*, so I am not sure about this. It might be calling *toString()* on the passed String argument, behind the scene.

Comment: I don't know what is the type of output but I doubt any method that is passed a String will again call toString on that object

Comment: Your doubt is correct, regarding System.out.println(). But I am not sure here. Edited the post to match the scenrio. Thanks, Hemal.

Answer (score 1):

What is the type of `output`? Does `output.print` method handle `null`?

Try checking if `rs.getObject(1)` is null before calling `output.print(rs.getString(1))`

Comment: I don't think rs.getObject() is worth a try. Posting the stack trace will work the best.

Answer (score 0):

Is the connection still active? Are you using a connection pool?

See if you can enable debug logging for that JDBC driver.

See if you can upgrade the driver to a new version.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the solution to this problem - the database connection was getting closed too early. I didn't realize that as soon as the db connection was closed that the record pointer would end up being null - I thought the resultset would be in system memory.

The solution is to close the connection after the while(rs.next()) loop terminates.

Thanks again.

Answer (score -2):

try wrap the stuff for accessing the data like :

if(rs!=null && rs.next())
{

// read the stuff

}

if still persists will advice to check the read value for null itself.

Comment: I believe Tim is looking for a way to fix the problem, not work around it.

Comment: This is not a work around. This will help him to nail down to the specific values which become null. I believe this is the way to start with.